# Get file names into NSString loaded from directory

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have loaded image files from local directory using:

```
fotosJugadores = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/Users/exular/Developer/GBC/exular/GBC/Caras/" error: &error];
```

How can I get each file name loaded into `NSString`?

Answer (score 4):

The `NSArray` returned from the method contains `NSString` objects where each object is a file/directory/symbol :

so for example to print the file names do :

```
fotosJugadores = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/Users/exular/Developer/GBC/exular/GBC/Caras/" error: &error];

for (NSString *file in fotosJugadores) {
    NSLog(@"File = %@", file);
}
```